# Behavior-ViewModel Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write a simple behavior with max- and min- values to validate an entered value within a certain range:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <Entry.Behaviors>
    <ui:ValueInRangeValidator x:Name="QtyValidator" MinValue="1" MaxValue="10"/>
  </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

This works fine, but when trying to add binding eg. `MaxValue="{Binding MaxVal}"` the value is left as it's default.

I'm using the following in my behavior:

```
public static BindableProperty MaxValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("MaxValue", typeof(decimal?), typeof(ValueInRangeValidator));
public decimal? MaxValue
{
    get { return (decimal?)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I've also tried setting the property changed event on the BindableProperty but it never seems to fire.  I know the viewmodel is correct as binding the same property to a label displays the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Entry x:Name="Entry1" 
       BindingContext="{Binding}" 
       Text="{Binding Quantity, 
       Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <ui:ValueInRangeValidator x:Name="QtyValidator" 
            MinValue="1" 
            MaxValue="{Binding BindingContext.MaxVal, Source={x:Reference Entry1}}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Comment: I added the name to the parent View instead, as it means I don't need to rebind or name the Entry control, and makes it accessible to the whole View in case you need it in multiple places.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: This exactly what I wanted. On side note, OnEntryTextChanged of entry fires up before MaxValue binds to the value. Any idea on how to stop it?

Comment: @Hasitha sorry, I'm afraid I do not know.